# php SimpleXML sort data key and value. Need to find top 10 values

Tags: php, xml, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I have an XML file that has the following data in…

```
<posts>
  <post id="22359">
    <postviews>31</postviews>
  </post>
  <post id="20963">
    <postviews>1</postviews>
  </post>
  <post id="20595">
    <postviews>3</postviews>
  </post>
  <post id="22640">
    <postviews>72</postviews>
  </post>
  <post id="22227">
    <postviews>1</postviews>
  </post>
...etc etc
</posts>
```

I'd like to find the top 10 highest postview values and then get the parent node post id so I'd essentially have the id's of the top 10 postviews.

I have no idea how to go about this, can anyone help? Is the XML file already an array if I load it via…

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
```

Thanks, James

Comment: Nope, SimpleXML uses dynamically generated objects rather than arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by adding each `post` SimpleXML element to an array, and then sorting that array using [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    if ((int)$a->postviews[0] == (int)$b->postviews[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ((int)$a->postviews[0] > (int)$b->postviews[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);

$posts = array();

foreach($xml->post as $p)
{
    $posts[] = $p;
}

usort($posts, "cmp");

// $posts is now sorted by the views

// output them
foreach($posts as $post)
{
  echo "Post ID " . $post->attributes()->id . " has " . (int)$post->postviews . " views\n";
}
```

If you only want the top 10 then just use a `for` loop or add a check to stop the loop after the first 10, or you can `unset()` everything after the first 10.

**Outputs**

> Post ID 22640 has 72 views
>   Post ID 22359 has 31 views
>   Post ID 20595 has 3 views
>   Post ID 22227 has 1 views
>   Post ID 20963 has 1 views

**[Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/s6MBg9GB)**

Comment: Works great thanks a lot @mrcode :-) I have changed the line `$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);` to `$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlStr);` as I'm loading the xml from a file.

James

Answer (score 0):

Edit: lol, You might want to use MrCode's example rather than mine. It completely slipped my mind that XML was interpreted separately.

Well, I've no experience with XML whatsoever. But I'll try to help, anyway.
Not sure how you want to read the XML file, but I'm going to use fgets() here:

```
$file_handle = fopen($xmlFile, "r");
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 31) { //We have the inital declaration, then 3 lines per read. 31.
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   echo $line;
$i++;
}
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Did this help any?

Comment: Thanks a lot Acronym TheRapper :-)

I've used @mrcode example as it's a lot more flexible in the long term